# why does my background color fill the whole screen when I run the app with simulator but not in my canvas preview?

Tags: ios, swift, canvas

I am building my first Swift app and I am trying to learn my way around things. For some reason, my background color fills the whole app when I run it through a simulator but not on my preview.

[image: shown in this screenshot]

I learned how to set up preview so that I can use canvas so that my app hot reloads while I code.

```swift
struct ViewControllerPreview: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ViewControllerWrapper()
    }
}

struct ViewControllerWrapper: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    typealias UIViewControllerType = ViewController
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> ViewController {
        return ViewController()
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: ViewController, context: Context) {
        // Update the view controller if needed
    }
}
```